# How should I say "where", as in mathematical definitions?

Tags: mathematics

I've been perusing several German books of logic and math to find some expression equivalent to "where" as in the following definition:

> **Definition:** Let *P(A,B) = A - B*, where *A ⊂ U* and *A ⊄ B*.

Is it okay if I translate it as follows?

> **Definition:** Sei *P(A,B) = A - B*, wo *A ⊂ U* und *A ⊄ B*.

Comment: Which dictionaries have you tried?

Comment: @Dan Do you think such dictionaries on the grammar of math exist? I don't. Thus I'll vote for reopening (after some edits) for this really needs expertise.

Comment: An die Close-Voter: diese spezielle Wendung steht in keinem Wörterbuch. So etwas lernt man erst durch Lesen vieler in Deutsch verfasster Mathematikbücher.

Comment: @Dan: I'd like to read in only *one* dictionary only *one* reference giving the answer to the OP's problem, that is: What would be a common translation for 'where' as a connector of side conditions in a given mathematical problem beginning with '_(gegeben) sei_'? Even if it exists it will be hard to find.

Comment: @Bjön Friedrich: So ist es, bzw. es reicht auch ein Mathematik-Grundkurs an der Uni vor Aufnahme eines mathematisch-naturwissenschaftlichen Studiums.

Comment: I would advise against "nicht ⊂" and rewrite it mathematically as "⊄"

Comment: @c.p. they do exist.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich auf die Weise kann man die Antwort in wenigen Sekunden selbstständig finden. https://www.google.com/search?q="wo+A"+mathematik&oq="wo+A"+mathematik

Comment: @Dan das ist Unfug. "[...], wo A [...] ist", ist schlechter Stil und das wird in deinen schönen Google Suchergebnissen leider nicht erwähnt.

Comment: @infinitezero wo hast du nur das "ist" her?

Comment: @Dan Evidence please

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two common ways of indicating restricting conditions. One way is to use a subordinate clause initiated with the pronomial adverb [*wobei*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wobei):

> **Definition:** Sei *P(A,B) = A - B*, wobei *A ⊂ U* und *A ⊄ B* gelten soll.

(Some language economists among the mathematicians might even drop *gelten soll*.)

A more succinct way is to use the preposition [*mit*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mit#Pr%C3%A4position) followed by the conditions:

> **Definition:** Sei *P(A,B) = A - B* mit *A ⊂ U* und *A ⊄ B*.

Using the subjunction [*wo*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wo#Subjunktion) is grammatically valid, but it is bad style. I cannot remember to have seen it anywhere in a mathematical text:

> **Definition:** Sei *P(A,B) = A - B*, wo *A ⊂ U* und *A ⊄ B*.

Comment: Unabhängig von der Frage: Sollte man "nicht A ⊂ B" nicht eher als "A ⊄ B", bzw. "¬ (A ⊂ B)" schreiben?

Comment: @mtwde Wenn man so Anfänger ist (wie man hier der mengentheoretische Kontext vorzuschlagen scheint)  ja, dein Vorschlag verbessert die Definition. Gleiches gilt für Vorlesungen. Aufsätze haben aber schon viele Symbole, da ist manchmal *plain English* (bzw. Deutsch) optisch besser. Daher empfinde ich das auch nicht falsch. Aber das ist wohl Geschmackssache.

Comment: "Sei ... mit ..." erscheint mir die eleganteste Lösung, und ich meine auch, die bislang am häufigsten gelesen zu haben.

Comment: @mtwde Bedenke, dass streng genommen jedes Zeichen definiert sein muss. Speziell in Lehrbüchern über Logik und formalen Systemen geht man sparsam damit um.

Answer (score 7):

This is a very reasonable question. The solution is to use *wobei* as in your example

P(A,B) = A - B, wobei A ⊂ U.

Using *wo* is not wrong in my opinion, but not so common.

Here is a real-life example: The attached file shows page 36 of the textbook *Approximation* by Armin Iske. There, you can see the use of *wobei* in theorem 2.17.[image: Page 36 of Iske: *Approximation*]

Comment: That book also uses *mit*.

Comment: But Theorem 2.17 starts with "Für *f* ∈ *L^n*, **mit** *n* ≥ 1 ..."

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Read the whole thing!